# how to assign images using javascript to div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
function ft1(){
        var imgSrcs = ['1.gif','2.gif','3.gif','4.gif','5.gif','6.gif','7.gif','8.gif']; 
        var myImages = [], img;
        for (var i = 1; i <=8; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {

                var div0 = document.getElementById(i);
                div0.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.src + ")";
            };
            img.src = imgSrcs[i];
            myImages[i] = img;
        }

        }


<input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="ft1();" />
```

> my div ids are 1 to 8. i want to add images for that dives using javascript.but this code didn't work properly. if u know where is the error plz tel me.

Comment: what does `this.src` refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your code:

```
function ft1() {
    var imgSrcs = ['1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif', '5.gif', '6.gif', '7.gif', '8.gif'];
    var myImages = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= imgSrcs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgSrcs[i];
        var div0 = document.getElementById(i);
        //I am not sure what you are trying to do in the below line.
        //div0.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.src + ")";
        div0.appendChild(img);
        myImages[i] = img;
    }
}
```

AFAIK, `img.onload` will not work because `img` variable is not part of DOM. First you need to make it part of DOM using `appendChild` method as shown above.

I have one question, what does `this.src` referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the help. please help me on this also. (draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="pic2") i wont to add these things to img. because i'm trying to do image puzzle.so the adding image can be drag and drop. Plz plz help me..

Comment: @A_J that is tricky part and needs to know all the possibilities from top to bottom. I am not good with jquery and jquery Ui. So, I can't help you in this.

Comment: i use javaScprit only. before i assign img element in this way (<img src="2.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="pic2" />
) now i wont to add this methods and id to img.

Comment: The JavaScript Image-object has a proporty `"onload"`! Regarding `this.src`: `this` is referring to an event's target (or source-element) in a standard-compliant browser. So `this.src` is the `src`-property of the image that has just been loaded.

Comment: @masswerk I can't find a link which states that Image-object has a property "onload".. Can you help me here?

Comment: @Mr_Green In short: open your console and try `new Image().onload !== undefined`.

Comment: @masswerk I get your point very long time ago. I was asking you to help me to get a link on specification. read my above comment again..

Comment: @Mr_Green The point was on the statement that an image would not load, if not added to the DOM. `img = new Image();` is just the "old" way of saying `img = document.createElement("img");`. (Before Netscape 4 the document wasn't available in the head-section, as this was only present, when the parser had reached the body-tag. Also, there hadn't been a regular DOM. So it worked by the document.images-array and by "new Image()", as introduced with NS3. Now it's not a top-level object but a descendant of the HtmlElement. "Image" still exists, but isn't extensively covered in the docs.)

Comment: @Mr_Green (continued) Since there was no DOM with NS3 and no way of manipulating a document already rendered and there were no means to manipulate the image itself, `Image.onload` was the very essence of the Image-object. You would use it for preloading (often in the head-section) and maybe refer to its src-property for applying a src-path to an element of the `document.images`-array. That's all you could do with it.

Comment: @masswerk Thank you for the above information which is from the past history of NS :p. Cheers..

Comment: @Mr_Green If you're really interested (and official documentation is hard to find) O'Reilley's "JavaScript – The Definitive Guide, 2nd Edition" lists the following properties: border, complete, height, hspace, lowsrc (NS only, used to display a low-bandwith-version of the image first while the normal src would be loading), name, src, vspace, width, and the handlers onabort, onerror, onload.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code in the loop

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.src = this.src;
elem.setAttribute("height", "250");
elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "alt text");
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use `imgSrcs[i]` instead of `this.src`

Comment: `this.src`is ok. `this` refers to the event's target (the image).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myImages = new Array("usa.gif","canada.gif","jamaica.gif","mexico.gif");// list of images

        function changeImg(that) // function call on_click of image below
    {
        var newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*3); // create math to random the images

        while (that.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1) // make sure that the randomization corresponds to the list of images
        {
            newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*3) // sets the math to the new image
        }

        that.src = myImages[newImgNumber]; // change the image 

        return false; // makes it able to be done again
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add images to all the divs, I would try simplifying it to:

```
function ft1(){
    var imgSrcs = ['1.gif','2.gif','3.gif','4.gif','5.gif','6.gif','7.gif','8.gif']; 
    for (i = 1; i <=8; i++) {
            var div = document.getElementById(i);
            div.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgSrcs[i] + ")";//make sure images are in the right folder
    }

}

<input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="ft1()" /> //remove semicolon
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle with color instead of images http://jsfiddle.net/CKFrantz/gLfXA/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the loop is probably that the loop-counter will be the same in all of the callbacks. (Mind that the closures just share the same scope, so the value will be 8 for all of them after the loop is exited.)

This can be overcome by a factory function (passing a simple value as argument will result in it being copied):

```
function loadImageToElement(id, imgscr) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        el.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.src + ")";
        // we could use just the same:
        // el.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgscr + ")";
    };
    img.src = imgscr;
    return img;
}

function ft1(){
    var imgSrcs = ['1.gif','2.gif','3.gif','4.gif','5.gif','6.gif','7.gif','8.gif']; 
    var myImages = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        myImages[i] = loadImageToElement('div' + (i+1), imgSrcs[i]);
    }
}

<input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="ft1();" />
```

Edit: you may want to check for `img.complete`:

```
function loadImageToElement(id, imgscr) {
    var img = new Image();
    var f = function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        el.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgsrc + ")";
    }
    img.src = imgscr;
    if (img.complete) {
        f();
    }
    else {
        img.onload = f;
    }
    return img;
}
```

(Note: `Image.complete` is `true`, if the image is already cached. In this case the onload-event wont fire in some browsers.)